# что такое HSTS и как его обойти с помощью /etc/hosts

Tags: http, https, hosts

Начал изучать сети и в скором времени наткнулся на файл `/etc/hosts`. Решил поэксперементировать и вписал в него всем известный (vk.com) с совершенно левым IP. Но при открытии браузер пишет следующие строки:

> The owner of vk.com has configured their website improperly. To
>   protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected
>   to this website.
>
> This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that
>   Firefox may only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not
>   possible to add an exception for this certificate.

Из чего возникает вопрос, как обойти эту блокировку и при вводе vk.com перейти на IP указанный мной.

Comment: Какую строку вы вписали в hosts?

Comment: Указать такой IP, по которому не будет происходить редиректа на HTTPS-протокол.

Answer (score 4):

[HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) - это механизим принудительного редиректа на HTTPS, который срабатывает на стороне сервера.

Вы когда-то открыли в браузере настоящий https://vk.com/, и он отдал вам заголовок следующего вида:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
```

Этот заголовок сохраняется в кэше браузера. При его наличии, при посещении этого домена делает две вещи:

- Принудительно, *без обращения на сервер*, перенаправляет вас на https
- Запрещает вам добавлять невалидный сертификат для этого сервера.

Т.е. неважно, что за сервер записан у вас в hosts, и что он отвечает по http - обращение к нему пойдет сразу по https, причем браузер будет ожидать валидного сертификата.

Для vk.com - (пока) достаточно почистить кэш браузера - Firefox забудет про заголовок и перестанет перебрасывать вас на https.

Для сайтов из HSTS Preload List ([Chrome](https://hstspreload.org/), [Mozilla](https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mozilla/security/manager/ssl/nsSTSPreloadList.inc)) чистка кэша не поможет, и заголовок механизм HSTS будет срабатывать принудительно.

Answer (score 1):

Вы подключаетесь по `TLS` на левый ресурс, назовем его `example.com`. Этот ресурс отправляет браузеру сертификат, выданный для домена `example.com`. Но браузер ожидает сертификат для `vk.com`, поэтому вы видите сообщение, что здесь что-то не так.

Что бы протестировать вашу задумку придется найти ресурс, который можно просматривать без защищенного соединения, то есть просто `http://`